# table content editable event

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Is there an event on table row content editable to get the value once the user press enter or the focus on edited cell has been loose. I'm just wondering if the user can modify on cell as much as he want and when he is done there is something like a button that apply the changes and do the one time update query on the table.

Currently I have table like this:

```
<table class="sortable" border="1" id="myTable" >
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID No</th>
              <th>Sec ID</th>
              <th>Employee</th>
              <th>Dept</th>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>Train</th>
              <th>Cert</th>
              <th>Prog</th>
              <th>Date</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          @foreach (var item in details)
          {
              <tr>                  
                  <td>@item.ID</td>
                  <td contenteditable='true' bgcolor="#F0F0F0">@item.secID</td>
                  <td>@item.name </td>
                  <td>@item.dept </td>
                  <td contenteditable='true' bgcolor="#F0F0F0">@item.Code </td>
                  <td contenteditable='true' bgcolor="#F0F0F0">@item.train </td>
                  <td contenteditable='true' bgcolor="#F0F0F0">@item.cert  </td>
                  <td contenteditable='true' bgcolor="#F0F0F0">@item.prog  </td>
                  <td>@item.date </td>
              </tr>
          }
      </tbody>
</table>
```

I just want to collect the edited rows and store it on variable or list and pass it to my update query via ajax.

Any suggestions/comments TIA.

Comment: You can use `$('#yourId').on('blur' , function(){}` to start a function when you loose focus

Comment: where can I put this on ready function or will I add onclick event to td?

Comment: put it in a script tag at the bottom but still inside of your `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this on change event handler:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    //do whatever
})
```

Comment: where can I put this?  on ready function or will I add onclick event to td?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want, it'll work perfectly.